# How to reload messages.en without restarting?

Tags: scala, playframework, internationalization

It seem that `messages.en` file only reloads when I recompile/restart the app. How can I reload it without restart in Prod mode.

I'm using Play 2.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved my problem thank to a good suggested direction from bjfletcher.

Basically, I disabled default messageapi from play framework by adding `defaultmessagesplugin=disabled` to `application.conf` and write a new message api plugin then enable it by adding a line `1001:services.DMessages` in `conf/play.plugins. The implementation of DMessages is:

```
package services
import play.api.Application
import play.api.i18n.{MessagesApi, MessagesPlugin}
class DMessages(app: Application) extends MessagesPlugin{
  override def enabled = true

  /**
   * This is where we read messages.en file and map it back to messages and pass into MessageApi
   * @return MessageApi that contained mapped messages
   */
  override def api: MessagesApi = {
    var messages:Map[String,Map[String,String]] = Map()
    messages = messages ++ Map("language" -> Map("key"-> "value")) //e.g. Map("en" -> Map("hello" -> "Hello world!"))
    MessagesApi(messages)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: bypass the dependency-injected singleton, and create our own `MessagesApi`:

```
implicit val messagesApi = new DefaultMessagesApi(Environment.simple(), current.configuration, new DefaultLangs(current.configuration))
```

Long answer:

Play's `MessagesApi` object is a singleton meaning we use the same instance at all time:

```
@Singleton
class DefaultMessagesApi @Inject() (environment: Environment, configuration: Configuration, langs: Langs) extends MessagesApi { ...
```

and its `messages` field which holds all the messages is immutable.

```
val messages: Map[String, Map[String, String]] = loadAllMessages
```

We can't modify it.

However... we can create a `MessagesApi` of our own and use that instead.  For example:

```
implicit val messagesApi = new DefaultMessagesApi(Environment.simple(), current.configuration, new DefaultLangs(current.configuration))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It seem that `DefaultMessagesApi` is only available in Play 2.4. Sorry that I forgot to mention that my current system is on play 2.3